# How does @NotNull and @Size work internally in springboot-validation?

Tags: spring, bean-validation

I want to understand how the @Size and @NotNull annotations are written. To do this i cloned the repo of https://github.com/jakartaee/validation .

I see this code

```
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER, TYPE_USE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Repeatable(List.class)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = { })
public @interface Size {

    String message() default "{jakarta.validation.constraints.Size.message}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default { };

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };

    /**
     * @return size the element must be higher or equal to
     */
    int min() default 0;

    /**
     * @return size the element must be lower or equal to
     */
    int max() default Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    /**
     * Defines several {@link Size} annotations on the same element.
     *
     * @see Size
     */
    @Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER, TYPE_USE })
    @Retention(RUNTIME)
    @Documented
    @interface List {

        Size[] value();
    }
}
```

I am unable to see the supporting class which is validating the size. Usually when we define a custom annotation we use something like

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = TimeFormatValidator.class)
```

I dont see that here.
I want to see the logic underneath.

Answer (score 1):

The repository you link to is only the API specification. For the constraint annotations specified in the validation API, it's up to the implementation to automatically configure validators. The most common implementation is [Hibernate Validator](https://hibernate.org/validator/). For instance:

- [NotNullValidator](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/main/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/internal/constraintvalidators/bv/NotNullValidator.java)
- [SizeValidatorForCollection](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-validator/blob/main/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/validator/internal/constraintvalidators/bv/size/SizeValidatorForCollection.java)